# Достоевский — этимология

Tags: этимология, фамилии

Какова этимология фамилии Достоевский? Может ли её первая часть быть чем-то вроде **досто**почтенный, **досто**верный?

Answer (score 5):

[Использованы данные Толкового словаря русского языка с включением сведений о происхождении слов (2007)](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9):

> От названия села **Достоево**, от сущ. **достой**, сравните: праслав.
>   *dostojьnъ, от кот. в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. достоиныи, ст.-слав. достоинъ, укр. достойний, белор. дастойны, болг. достоен,
>   макед. достоен, сербск. достојан и др.; от *dostojь, связанн. со
>   *stojati (стоять).

Другой источник рассказывает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]